# How to configure jackson with spring globally?

Tags: java, spring, jackson

To serialize deserialize object I am useing Jackson as flow

```
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
private LocalDate openingDate
```

How do I make this the default globally so I do not have to add it to every property ?

Using XML configuration.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Java-based configuration, you can create your configuration class extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and do the following:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    converters.add(converter);
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}
```

In here, you can configure the ObjectMapper as you like and set it as a converter.

Answer (score 6):

With Spring Boot you can achieve this by registering new `Module`.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Module module() {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("Module", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, null, null));
        module.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeSerializer());
        module.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer());

        return module;
    }
}
```

As stated in documentation [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers)

> Jackson 1.7 added ability to register serializers and deserializes via
>   Module interface. This is the recommended way to add custom
>   serializers -- all serializers are considered "generic", in that they
>   are used for subtypes unless more specific binding is found.

and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper):

> Any beans of type `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module` are
>   automatically registered with the auto-configured
>   `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` and are applied to any `ObjectMapper`
>   instances that it creates. This provides a global mechanism for
>   contributing custom modules when you add new features to your
>   application.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can install modules for using things like java datetime or jodatime. checkout this:

```
    @Bean
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder() {
        JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
        module.addSerializer(OffsetDateTime.class, JSR310DateTimeSerializer.INSTANCE);
        module.addSerializer(ZonedDateTime.class, JSR310DateTimeSerializer.INSTANCE);
        module.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, JSR310DateTimeSerializer.INSTANCE);
        module.addSerializer(Instant.class, JSR310DateTimeSerializer.INSTANCE);
        module.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, JSR310LocalDateDeserializer.INSTANCE);
        return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
                .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                .findModulesViaServiceLoader(true)
                .modulesToInstall(module);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use configure your serializers (providing fully qualified class name) in spring `Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean` then bind it with  `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. Here is an example `XML` configuration snippet:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
   <property name="objectMapper">
     <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean"
       p:failOnEmptyBeans="false"
       p:indentOutput="true">
       <property name="serializers">
         <array>
           <bean class="LocalDateSerializer" />
         </array>
       </property>
     </bean>
   </property>
 </bean>
```

The [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean.html) to the documentation

Answer (score 1):

One more solution similar to @Jaiwo99 in the thread. We can register JavaTime module directly to ObjectMapper

```
@Bean
public Object registerJavaTimeModuleForJackson(){
    return new Object(){
        @Autowired
        private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

        @PostConstruct
        public void registerJavaTimeModuleForJackson(){
           objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        }
    };
}
```

I am using springboot 2.4.5

Answer (score 0):

I tried some of answered solutions but none of them worked for me and this is what i did

```java
@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.forEach(converter -> {
        if(converter.getClass().equals(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class)) {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter).getObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        }
    });
}
```

And use `extendMessageConverters` instead of `configureMessageConverters` since it turns off default converter registration.